# Clipboard.js - Page jumps on copy when using IOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com) and it works great on desktop. However, when viewing my site from an iPhone, the page scrolls either up or down dramatically when you press a button to click to copy.

Link to the site: [symbolgrab.com](https://symbolgrab.com)

Below is my code.

```js
// Tooltip
jQuery('button').tooltip({
  trigger: 'click',
  placement: 'bottom',
});

function setTooltip(btn, message) {
  jQuery(btn).tooltip('hide')
    .attr('data-original-title', message)
    .tooltip('show');
}

function hideTooltip(btn) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery(btn).tooltip('hide');
  }, 1000);
}

// Clipboard

var clipboard = new Clipboard('button');

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
  setTooltip(e.trigger, 'Copied!');
  hideTooltip(e.trigger);
});

clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
  setTooltip(e.trigger, 'Unable to Copy');
  hideTooltip(e.trigger);
});
```

```css
.btn {
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
 background-color:#ffffff;
 -moz-border-radius:28px;
 -webkit-border-radius:28px;
 border-radius:8px;
 border:1px solid #000000;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#000000;
 font-family:Times New Roman;
 font-size:38px;
 padding:5px 20px;
 text-decoration:none;
 width:90px;
 height:70px;
 margin-right:10px;
 margin-top:10px;
 position: relative;
}
.btn:hover {
 background-color:#f2f2f2;
}

.btn:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn"  data-clipboard-action="copy" title="Text to Copy" alt="Text to Copy" data-clipboard-text="Text to Copy">Text to Copy</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.5.10/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

The copy to clipboard function works, the only issue is that the page just jumps. The further you scroll down the page, the more the page jumps downward. When you're near the top, the page jumps upward. Not sure what is causing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Also having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I worked all day on this, and finally found a way to minimize the problem.

In your css file:

```
textarea {
   position: fixed;
   top:50% !important;
   bottom:50% !important;
   height: 0.02px !important;
   background-color: black !important;
}
```

I added this to the existing

```
textarea {
   overflow: auto;
}
```

It still jumps a tiny bit, but it's either barely noticeable, or not at all, depending on your element layout.

If I completely hide it with `display: none !important` it just doesn't copy any text, so this is the only decent solution for me at the moment.